# Does a Positive integer exist that can convert...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can you prove or disprove the existence of a positive integer P, such that P can convert the expression;

$6ab+a+b$   into the form $6xy+x-y$ by subtracting from it.

What I am trying to find is a positive integer P that makes Z, in the following equation,expressible in the form;
$6xy+ x - y$

$Z=6ab+a+b-P$

for all $a$ and $b$
where $a,b,x,y,∈N $ , $P>0 $

Clarification:

Say if ;

$Z=2K+1-P$, and you want to find and expression P that would make Z be of the form $2a-1$

Then $P=4$ would be an example of such a number,
Since then;

$Z=2k+1-2-2=2(k-1)-1$

Comment: Can you supply some context or an example on this? It's hard to grasp what you really want to achieve here.

Comment: E.g. $P = 6ab + a + b - (6xy + x - y)$?

Comment: P cannot involve the variables $a$ or $b$

Comment: Note that your example $2K + 1$ is already (by subtracting zero) of the form $2(K+1) - 1$.  So I'm not sure how much subtracting something (if cannot involve $a$ or $b$) enlarges the possibilities.  Probably what you mean is to subtract a constant, and then rewrite the resulting expression in a form $6xy + x - y$.

Comment: I think that would make more sense.